# Why are 666 the default file creation permissions?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, files

As I've found out, when using umask, the highest permissions you can give to files are 666.
Which is done by `umask 0000`. That's because of the default file creation permissions, which appear to be 666 on every system that I know.

I know for files we need executable rights to show their contents.
 But why do we limit the default file creation permissions on 666?

Comment: What kind of system? The only `umask` I met was always 0022, creating default permission 644.

Comment: No you misunderstood. Umask is using the default file permissions of 666 and substracts its own value (which is 0022 for your system). So the most permissions you could set is `umask 0000` - which still limits to file permissions of 666. (But apparently folders use 777)

Comment: Got you. Now this is a good question.

Comment: You don't need executable permissions to see file contents. This is so for _directories_ which is why directories are created by default with execute permissions.

Comment: Why don't we just allow 777 for files? Even though we don't need it, we should not limit or disallow.

Comment: I believe [but would need to look more to be sure] that this is by design, to avoid some security problems: without access to "chmod", you can't make a file executable. umask 0000 creates files with 0666 and directories with 0777 [which, by the way, is quite an awful default setting, security wise!]

Comment: it seems also sane that a default mode creation (before umask) to be "666" instead of "777" for files. Forcing one to explicitely give execute permission to the appropriate part (U, G or O). Hence you see a "666-umask" result.

Comment: @JosephR.: actually the x in directories is for "trasversal" rights, not read ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Well, I just tested it, you can't `stat` a non-executable directory or any of its contents, should you know their names.

Comment: @JosephR: because for that you need to reach `dir/.` ("inside" dir)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is hard-coded into standard utilities. I `strace`d both a `touch` creating a new file and a `mkdir` creating a new directory.

The `touch` trace produced this:

```
open("newfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

while the `mkdir` trace produced this:

```
mkdir("newdir", 0777)                   = 0
```

Short of coding the file/directory creation process in C, I don't see a way of modifying the default permissions. It seems to me, though, that not making files executable by default makes sense: you don't want any random text to be accidentally misconstrued as shell commands.

**Update**

To give you an example of how the permission bits are hard-coded into the standard utilities. Here are some relevant lines from two files in the `coreutils` package that contains the source code for both `touch(1)` and `mkdir(1)`, among others:

`mkdir.c`:

```
if (specified_mode)
   {   
     struct mode_change *change = mode_compile (specified_mode);
     if (!change)
       error (EXIT_FAILURE, 0, _("invalid mode %s"),
              quote (specified_mode));
     options.mode = mode_adjust (S_IRWXUGO, true, umask_value, change,
                                  &options.mode_bits);
     free (change);
   }   
  else
    options.mode = S_IRWXUGO & ~umask_value;
}
```

In other words, if the mode is not specified, set it to `S_IRWXUGO` (read: 0777) modified by the `umask_value`.

`touch.c` is even clearer:

```
int default_permissions =
  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
```

That is, give read and write permissions to everyone (read: 0666), which will be modified by the process `umask` on file creation, of course.

You may be able to get around this programmatically only: i.e. while creating files from within either a C program, where you make the system calls directly or from within a language that allows you to make a low-level syscall (see for example Perl's `sysopen` under `perldoc -f sysopen`).

Comment: You are right, I don't want any accidents. But to have no way to change it, is awful! Standard values should be 777. And we need `umask file` and `umask dir`. Set two different default values and fine. But now I have no way to create files with exec perms.

Comment: @PeterI Well, `mkdir(1)` does offer you a `-m` switch to specify the directory's mode at creation time. With files, however, since file creation uses the `open(2)` syscall, the tool you use to create the file is the one that's responsible for passing the mode bits to `open` and you don't get a say in the matter. `install(1)` by default copies your file to a new location and sets the execute bits, but that's still not happening at creation time.

Comment: What you are saying, that `touch` for example is responsible to set the right values. Do you know where it stores the values? Maybe they are set systemwide - so we could change them? Because I want to *break free* ;)

Comment: @PeterI See the updated answer.

Comment: Awsome lookup. I thank you very much. I know now, where the restrictions are set. But what we need here is a change. Things should change to 777. And modified default umask values.

Comment: @PeterI I updated the answer again. You may be able to make the syscall directly from within either C or another language like Perl.

Comment: Interesrting question and answer!

Comment: http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/umask-define-linuxunix.html here is useful link (at least to me)

Answer (score 7):

First off, there is no global default, the permissions depend on the application that creates the file. For example, this little C program will create a file '/tmp/foo' with permissions 0777 if umask is 0000 (in any case permissions will be 0777 & ~umask):

```
int main() 
{
   creat("/tmp/foo", 0777);
   return 0;
}
```

That being said, many applications create files with permissions of 0666. That has two reasons:

1. Security: you do not want any arbitrary file to be executable.
2. Convenience: most files do not need to be executable. It is easier to set the executable bit on a select few files than to unset it on the huge amount of other files. Of course, umask 0133 would solve this, but then nothing is won and you couldn't let programs create executable files even if you wanted to.

Comment: Files are created without the x(execute) bit set for security reasons.  The inadvertent execution of files [cw]ould be a "Bad Thing"(tm).  The chmod program gives you ability to (re)set permissions bits as needed.